# Serving Applications from Linux server to Chromebooks/Browsers?

Tags: virtualization, remote-desktop-services, xenapp, vdi

I'm looking for a way to serve desktop applications (RemoteApp style) to a Chromebook (or other web browser), but running on a Linux server. All of the systems I've come across thus far (XenApp, VMWare HorizonView) are for virtualising Windows apps.

I'm aware I could do this with VNC/RDP for entire desktops, but I'm wanting to only send a single application rather than the whole desktop.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

X11 has been doing this for AGES.

X11 allows for displays to run over the network.  This can open the entire desktop or just a single program, and will act like that program were running locally.  Security is an issue - usually X forwarding is done over SSH to provide encryption.

Chromebooks do provide some limited support for X forwarding over SSH.  You will have to try it and see if it works well for you.  This blog post is one example of someone using it on a chromebook: http://blog.tomtasche.at/2012/01/developing-on-chromebook-part-3-x.html?m=1

Comment: I'm looking to run the virtualapps on a chromebook or inside a web-browser. X11 doesn't help me here...

Comment: @askvictor missed that somehow.  Answer revised for chromebooks.